# std::ifstream::read ignores new line byte

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read the entire file into a buffer but the new line bytes('\n') are being ignored for some reason. Any ideas why?

```
std::ifstream fin( p_FilePath.c_str( ), std::ifstream::binary );

if( !fin.is_open( ) )
{
    return false;
}

fin.seekg( 0, std::ios::end );
int FileSize = fin.tellg( );
fin.seekg( 0, std::ios::beg );

char * pData = new char[ FileSize ];
fin.read( pData, FileSize );
```

Comment: The new line character `\n` is by default the delimiter for stream insertion.

Comment: How do you know they are being ignored?

Comment: I'm debugging the array and I can clearly see how the next line immediately starts after last one without any new line byte.

Comment: Are you using a Mac? The line separator for text on Macs is `'\r'`, which the standard library will translate into `'\n'` for you if you don't use `std::ifstream::binary`.

Comment: Nope, windows. Checking for \r fixed it. It seems like the new line bytes are ignored by Visual Studio's debugger

Comment: @grimgrom: Debuggers should only be used to quickly inspect, not really *test*. But if you really want to test, inspect the raw memory in the memory viewer. You should self-answer, stating your test for the newlines being ignored was a mistake, the debugger just formatted differently than you expected.